# wp rest api post per category per page

Tags: wordpress, api

Hei guys I want to make some homepage with only 3 WordPress post with `category = news`, so my category news id was 7. I can retrieve all post in category news with this URL

> /wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=7

but it gives me all post in the news category. I want only `3 posts` in category news if you can help me it's good guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass `per_page=‌3` in URL as:

```
/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=7&per_page=‌3
```